# How to retrieve data from sqlite in desc order and disply in text view

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Can anyone help me trying to retrieve data in desc order and displaying it in textview in revers order as latest entry will be shown first?

This query is correct in mysql

customer is 1st table and history table has customers historical data

app is working fine but when i tried to get data in desc order it is unfortunately closed.

even i tried for only one "cost" column still app it is unfortunately closed.

```
public StringBuilder getData(String custname)
{
    String query="select h.lsd , h.work,h.cost from  "+c_tablename+" c, "+h_tablename+" h where name='"+custname+"' and c.bike_number=h.bike_number ORDER BY lsd DESC";
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null,lsd+"DESC");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder =new StringBuilder();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if ( cursor !=null )// cursor!=null  error --  android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,
    {

        do {
            //cursor.moveToFirst();

            String lsd=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lsd"));
            stringBuilder.append("Date:"+lsd+"\n");

            String lwd=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("work"));
            stringBuilder.append("Work:"+lwd+"\n");

            String cost=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cost"));
            stringBuilder.append("Cost:"+cost");

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();


    }

    return stringBuilder;
}
```

in above code the query is executing correct till

String query="select h.lsd , h.work,h.cost from  "+c_tablename+" c, "+h_tablename+" h where name='"+custname+"' and c.bike_number=h.bike_number";

and displaying data as 1st entry 1st and last entry last

but when I put order by clause order by lsd desc  the app is unfortunately closed.

```
String query="select h.lsd , h.work,h.cost from  "+c_tablename+" c, "+h_tablename+" h where name='"+custname+"' and c.bike_number=h.bike_number ORDER BY lsd DESC";
```

01-12 23:57:16.599 4046-4059/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+user+0+com_google_android_gms+databases+metrics_db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Comment: 'the app is unfortunately closed' is a crash, please provide stacktrace from logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error you faced because there may be possibility that you have no data in your table so you have to check if there is any data or not?

Just try this.

```
if ( cursor !=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
    //do your stuff
}
```

You have to specify the specific column because there may be `lsd` column in both table so be specific in writing query like

Just try this

```
String query="select h.lsd , h.work,h.cost from "+c_tablename+" c, "+h_tablename+" h where name='"+custname+"' and c.bike_number=h.bike_number ORDER BY h.lsd DESC";
```

Comment: An alternative would be to use `while (cursor.moveToNext()) { ..yourstuff.. }`. If there are no rows then the loop is never entered.